# Magento 2.3.3 Duplicate entry '15-Images' after upgrade

Tags: magento2.3.3, setup-upgrade

I'm currently trying to upgrade data and one of my modules is throwing an obscure error about duplicated entry `eav_attribute_group` when I'm trying to install some product attribute,

I have installed product attributes before in another module with no errors,
Also, I've read that this issue comes up when migrating from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.
But this is a fresh Magento 2.3.3 installation.

UpgradeData.php UpgradeData::upgrade() // in upgrade section

```
// Add eav attributes.
        // Select Int.
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_INTENSITY, '', 13);
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_AROMA, '', 10);
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_BITTERNESS, '', 10);
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_ACIDITY, '', 10);
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_BODY, '', 10);
        $this->_addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_TOASTING_LEVEL, '', 9);
        // Image.
        $this->_addSimpleMediaAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_GEOGRAPHICAL_IMAGE,
            'Geographical'
        );
        // Text editor.
        $this->_addSimpleTexteditorAttribute(Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_ORIGIN);
        $this->_addSimpleTexteditorAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_TOASTING_DESCRIPTION,
            'Toasting Description'
        );
        $this->_addSimpleTexteditorAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_AROMATIC_LABEL,
            'Aromatic Label'
        );
        // Select.
        $this->_addSimpleSelectAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_DISPLAYED_AROMATIC_FAMILY,
            'Displayed Aromatic Family',
            [
                'Balanced',
                'Cramel',
                'Fruity',
                'Intense',
            ]
        );
        // Multiselect.
        $this->_addSimpleMultiselectAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIZE_CUP,
            'Size Cup',
            [
                'Espresso',
                'Lungo',
                'Milk',
                'Ristretto'
            ]
        );
        $this->_addSimpleMultiselectAttribute(
            Helper::EAV_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_AROMATIC_PROFILES,
            'Aromatic Profiles',
            [
                'Balanced',
                'caramel',
                'cereal',
                'Cocoa',
                'condiment',
                'Floral',
                'Fruity',
                'Intense',
                'Mild',
                'Powerful',
                'roasted',
                'woody'
            ]
        );
```

UpgradeData.php in the helper methods section

```
/**
 * Returns attribute configuration attribute boilerplate
 * with attribute custom configurations
 *
 * @param array $customConfig
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAttributeConfigArray(array $customConfig=[]) : array
{
    return array_merge([
        'group'                   => 'General',
        'type'                    => 'text',
        'backend'                 => '',
        'frontend'                => '',
        'label'                   => '',
        'input'                   => 'text',
        'class'                   => '',
        'source'                  => '',
        'global'                  => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => false,
        'user_defined'            => true,
        'searchable'              => true,
        'filterable'              => true,
        'comparable'              => false,
        'visible_on_front'        => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique'                  => false,
        'apply_to'                => '',
        'sort_order'              => 0,
    ], $customConfig);
}

/**
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $attributeLable
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
protected function _addSimpleMediaAttribute(string $attributeCode, string $attributeLable='') : void
{
    $config = $this->_getAttributeConfigArray([
        'group' => 'Images',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'label' => $attributeLable ?: ucfirst($attributeCode),
        'input' => 'media_image',
        'source'=> Image::class,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'sort_order' => ++self::$sortOrder,
    ]);
    $this->_eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $config);
}

/**
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $attributeLable
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
protected function _addSimpleTexteditorAttribute(string $attributeCode, string $attributeLable='') : void
{
    $config = $this->_getAttributeConfigArray([
        'label' => $attributeLable ?: ucfirst($attributeCode),
        'input' => 'texteditor',
        'sort_order' => ++self::$sortOrder,
    ]);

    $this->_eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $config);
}

/**
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $attributeLable
 * @param array $options
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
protected function _addSimpleSelectAttribute(string $attributeCode, string $attributeLable='', array $options=[]) : void
{
    $config = $this->_getAttributeConfigArray([
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'label' => $attributeLable ?: ucfirst($attributeCode),
        'input' => 'select',
        'sort_order' => ++self::$sortOrder,
        'option'     => $options,
    ]);

    $this->_eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $config);
}

/**
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $attributeLable
 * @param int $max
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
protected function _addSimpleIntSelectAttribute(string $attributeCode, string $attributeLable='', $max = 0) : void
{
    $i = 0;
    $options = [];
    while ($i <= $max) {
        $options[] = $i;
        $i++;
    }
    $this->_addSimpleSelectAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeLable, $options);
}

/**
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $attributeLable
 * @param array $options
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
 */
protected function _addSimpleMultiselectAttribute(string $attributeCode, string $attributeLable='', array $options=[]) : void
{
    $config = $this->_getAttributeConfigArray([
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'label' => $attributeLable ?: ucfirst($attributeCode),
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'sort_order' => ++self::$sortOrder,
        'option'     => $options,
    ]);

    $this->_eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $config);
}
```

[image: error]